# getStaticProps with getStaticPaths but changes don't affect

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

So, In `Next.js`, I'm trying to build a website, that has products, and I want to build each page for SEO and inject Meta tags so the Google can index them correctly, but for example the content inside can change also other stuff, and I don't know to handle this, what I can do in this case?

Comment: I assume that you are fetching from an API. Use [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes), import `Head` from [next/head](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) and use the data from `getStaticProps` to populate head's `title`, `description` etc.

Comment: Please try to reformulate your question. I do not understand you. Take a look at [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet), if you want to inject meta tags.